# why does yaml giving error while parsing hyphen

Tags: node.js, yaml

I have loaded an yaml file with js-yaml library ,but when i access a tag inside the yaml file which has an hyphen in between , i am getting reference error.Is there anyway i can escape the hyphen in my code.I am using nodejs application to load this. Below is my yaml syntax and code i tried to access it.

---

```
let spec = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'providerapi.yaml'), 

'utf8');
let oasDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);
let apiname = oasDoc.info.provider-api-name
```

but when i access this tag "provider-api-name" its throwing reference error. Is there anyway i can read/parse this correctly. Same issue with "provider-api-configuration".

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.4
  title: API
  provider-api-name: myapi
provider-api-configuration:
  testable:true
```

Thanks in Advance, Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You write "yaml giving error" but I see no **error message** in your question post...

Comment: Please, [edit] your question post and add the error messages into it. Comments are not suitable for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Javascript notation of square brackets and fixed this issue.